# Display none em chrome para iphone

Tags: css, iphone

Estou tentando esconder itens de um *dropdown* pelo `value`. No *Chrome* do computador e *Android* funcionou, porém no *iPhone* não:

```
option[value="home-01"]{
  display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O Safari impede que elementos de formulário sejam alterados por css usando display: none. Longa história.

A alterantiva seria manipular esses options usando js.

Existem inúmeros casos com esse mesmo problema no SO. Todos com a mesma resposta: não dá. [Veja aqui um post parecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025555/option-style-display-none-not-working-in-safari).